# Given polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $n$ find $g(x)$ of degree $n+1$ that passes through all points as $f(x)$ and an additional point

Tags: polynomials, interpolation

I am sure this is a simple standard textbook problem but I seem to have forgotten the basic steps.

**Problem:** Given a polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $n$ that passes through $n+1$ points and an additional point $P(x_{n+2}, y_{n+2})$, we want to construct the degree-$n+1$ polynomial $g(x)$ such that it passes through all the $n+1$ points of $f(x)$ and also through $P$.

I recall there is a simple construction for this in the lines of Lagrange Interpolation (when the points are specified), but don't remember the details of the interpolation when the polynomial is given and we just want to add more points. Can anyone help?

Comment: Hint: add a multiple of $(x-x_1)(x-x_2)\dots(x-x_{n+1}).$

Comment: What if we only have the polynomial $f(x)$ and not the points that were used to interpolate it and we want to add a point and build a new interpolating polynomial? In theory, we could just do $n+1$ evaluations of $f(x)$ and rebuild $g(x)$, but I thought there was a simpler construction that used $f(x)$ directly.

Comment: Certainly not possible if you don't know the $n+1$ $x$ values that you need to match.

Comment: Got it. Newton's forward difference formula with the last term added for the new point.